# ActiveMQ - Redelivery policy and Dead letter queue for topic

Tags: jms, amqp, spring-jms, activemq-artemis, atomikos

I'm working with ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17 and Spring Boot 2.5.7.
I'm publishing messages on topic and queue and consuming it. All is done through JMS.
All queues (anycast or multicast) are durables. My topic (multicast address) has 2 durable queues in order to have 2 separate consumers.
For my topic, the 2 consumers use durable and shared subscriptions (JMS 2.0).
All processing is transactional, managed through Atomikos transaction manager (I need it for a 2 phases commit with the database).

I have a problem with the redelivery policy and DLQ. When I throw an exception during the processing of the message, the redelivery policy applies correctly for the queue (anycast queue) and a DLQ is created with the message. However, for the topic (multicast queue), the redelivery policy does not apply and the message is not sent into a DLQ.

Here is my ActiveMQ Artemis broker configuration:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

        <name>0.0.0.0</name>


        <!-- Codec and key used to encode the passwords -->
        <!-- TODO : set master-password configuration into the Java code -->
        <password-codec>org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.DefaultSensitiveStringCodec;key=UBNTd0dS9w6f8HDIyGW9
        </password-codec>


        <!-- Configure the persistence into a database (postgresql) -->
        <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
        <store>
            <database-store>
                <bindings-table-name>BINDINGS_TABLE</bindings-table-name>
                <message-table-name>MESSAGE_TABLE</message-table-name>
                <page-store-table-name>PAGE_TABLE</page-store-table-name>
                <large-message-table-name>LARGE_MESSAGES_TABLE</large-message-table-name>
                <node-manager-store-table-name>NODE_MANAGER_TABLE</node-manager-store-table-name>
                <jdbc-lock-renew-period>2000</jdbc-lock-renew-period>
                <jdbc-lock-expiration>20000</jdbc-lock-expiration>
                <jdbc-journal-sync-period>5</jdbc-journal-sync-period>
                <!-- Configure a connection pool -->
                <data-source-properties>
                    <data-source-property key="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
                    <data-source-property key="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/artemis"/>
                    <data-source-property key="username" value="postgres"/>
                    <data-source-property key="password" value="ENC(-3eddbe9664c85ec7ed63588b000486cb)"/>
                    <data-source-property key="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
                    <data-source-property key="initialSize" value="2"/>
                    <data-source-property key="minIdle" value="1"/>
                </data-source-properties>
            </database-store>
        </store>


        <!-- Configure the addresses, queues and topics default behaviour -->
        <!-- See: https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html -->
        <address-settings>
            <address-setting match="#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLA</dead-letter-address>
                <auto-create-dead-letter-resources>true</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>
                <dead-letter-queue-prefix/>
                <dead-letter-queue-suffix>.DLQ</dead-letter-queue-suffix>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <auto-create-expiry-resources>false</auto-create-expiry-resources>
                <expiry-queue-prefix/>
                <expiry-queue-suffix>.EXP</expiry-queue-suffix>
                <expiry-delay>-1</expiry-delay>
                <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
                <redelivery-delay>250</redelivery-delay>
                <redelivery-delay-multiplier>2.0</redelivery-delay-multiplier>
                <redelivery-collision-avoidance-factor>0.5</redelivery-collision-avoidance-factor>
                <max-redelivery-delay>10000</max-redelivery-delay>
                <max-size-bytes>100000</max-size-bytes>
                <page-size-bytes>20000</page-size-bytes>
                <page-max-cache-size>5</page-max-cache-size>
                <max-size-bytes-reject-threshold>-1</max-size-bytes-reject-threshold>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>0</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <default-last-value-queue>false</default-last-value-queue>
                <default-non-destructive>false</default-non-destructive>
                <default-exclusive-queue>false</default-exclusive-queue>
                <default-consumers-before-dispatch>0</default-consumers-before-dispatch>
                <default-delay-before-dispatch>-1</default-delay-before-dispatch>
                <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
                <send-to-dla-on-no-route>true</send-to-dla-on-no-route>
                <slow-consumer-threshold>-1</slow-consumer-threshold>
                <slow-consumer-policy>NOTIFY</slow-consumer-policy>
                <slow-consumer-check-period>5</slow-consumer-check-period>
                <!-- We disable the automatic creation of queue or topic -->
                <auto-create-queues>false</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-delete-queues>true</auto-delete-queues>
                <auto-delete-created-queues>false</auto-delete-created-queues>
                <auto-delete-queues-delay>30000</auto-delete-queues-delay>
                <auto-delete-queues-message-count>0</auto-delete-queues-message-count>
                <config-delete-queues>OFF</config-delete-queues>
                <!-- We disable the automatic creation of address -->
                <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
                <auto-delete-addresses>true</auto-delete-addresses>
                <auto-delete-addresses-delay>30000</auto-delete-addresses-delay>
                <config-delete-addresses>OFF</config-delete-addresses>
                <management-browse-page-size>200</management-browse-page-size>
                <default-purge-on-no-consumers>false</default-purge-on-no-consumers>
                <default-max-consumers>-1</default-max-consumers>
                <default-queue-routing-type>ANYCAST</default-queue-routing-type>
                <default-address-routing-type>ANYCAST</default-address-routing-type>
                <default-ring-size>-1</default-ring-size>
                <retroactive-message-count>0</retroactive-message-count>
                <enable-metrics>true</enable-metrics>
                <!-- We automatically force group rebalance and a dispatch pause during group rebalance -->
                <default-group-rebalance>true</default-group-rebalance>
                <default-group-rebalance-pause-dispatch>true</default-group-rebalance-pause-dispatch>
                <default-group-buckets>1024</default-group-buckets>
            </address-setting>
        </address-settings>


        <!-- Define the protocols accepted -->
        <!-- See: https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/protocols-interoperability.html -->
        <acceptors>
            <!-- Acceptor for only CORE protocol -->
            <!-- We enable the cache destination as recommended into the documentation. See: https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-jms.html -->
            <acceptor name="artemis">
                tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?protocols=CORE,tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;useEpoll=true,cacheDestinations=true
            </acceptor>
        </acceptors>


        <!-- Define how to connect to another broker -->
        <!-- TODO : est-ce utile ? -->
        <connectors>
            <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
            <connector name="broker1-connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
            <connector name="broker2-connector">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
        </connectors>

        <!-- Configure the High-Availability and broker cluster for the high-availability -->
        <ha-policy>
            <shared-store>
                <master>
                    <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
                </master>
            </shared-store>
        </ha-policy>

        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="gerico-cluster">
                <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
                <static-connectors>
                    <connector-ref>broker1-connector</connector-ref>
                    <connector-ref>broker2-connector</connector-ref>
                </static-connectors>
            </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>

        <!--       <cluster-user>cluster_user</cluster-user>-->
        <!--       <cluster-password>cluster_user_password</cluster-password>-->

        <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
        <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

        <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

        <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

        <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>


        <page-sync-timeout>72000</page-sync-timeout>


        <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit.
       This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

        The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
        You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

        <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size>

  -->

        <!-- Security configuration -->
        <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>

        <!-- Addresses and queues configuration -->
        <!-- !!! DON'T FORGET TO UPDATE 'slave-broker.xml' FILE !!! -->
        <addresses>
            <address name="topic.test_rde">
                <multicast>
                    <queue name="rde_receiver_1">
                        <durable>true</durable>
                    </queue>
                    <queue name="rde_receiver_2">
                        <durable>true</durable>
                    </queue>
                </multicast>
            </address>
            <address name="queue.test_rde">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="queue.test_rde">
                        <durable>true</durable>
                    </queue>
                </anycast>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </core>
</configuration>
```

The JMS configuration into the Spring Boot is the following:

```
    @Bean
    public DynamicDestinationResolver destinationResolver() {
        return new DynamicDestinationResolver() {
            @Override
            public Destination resolveDestinationName(Session session, String destinationName, boolean pubSubDomain) throws JMSException {
                if (destinationName.startsWith("topic.")) {
                    pubSubDomain = true;
                }
                else
                    pubSubDomain =false;
                return super.resolveDestinationName(session, destinationName, pubSubDomain);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> queueConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                 DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
                                                                 JmsErrorHandler jmsErrorHandler) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setPubSubDomain(false);

        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);

        factory.setErrorHandler(jmsErrorHandler);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> topicConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                 DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
                                                                 JmsErrorHandler jmsErrorHandler) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);

        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        factory.setSubscriptionShared(true);

        factory.setErrorHandler(jmsErrorHandler);

        return factory;
    }
```

The messages publisher:

```
    @GetMapping("api/send")
    public void sendDataToJms() throws InterruptedException {

        OrderRest currentService = this.applicationContext.getBean(OrderRest.class);
        for (Long i = 0L; i < 1L; i++) {
            currentService.sendTopicMessage(i);
            currentService.sendQueueMessage(i);
            Thread.sleep(200L);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void sendTopicMessage(Long id) {
        Order myMessage = new Order("--" + id.toString() + "--", new Date());
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("topic.test_rde", myMessage);
    }
    @Transactional
    public void sendQueueMessage(Long id) {
        Order myMessage = new Order("--" + id.toString() + "--", new Date());
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("queue.test_rde", myMessage);
    }
```

And the listeners:

```
    @Transactional
    @JmsListener(destination = "topic.test_rde", containerFactory = "topicConnectionFactory", subscription = "rde_receiver_1")
    public void receiveMessage_rde_1(@Payload Order order, @Headers MessageHeaders headers, Message message, Session session) {
        log.info("---> Consumer1 - rde_receiver_1 - " + order.getContent());

            throw new ValidationException("Voluntary exception", "entity", List.of(), List.of());
    }

    @Transactional
    @JmsListener(destination = "queue.test_rde", containerFactory = "queueConnectionFactory")
    public void receiveMessage_rde_queue(@Payload Order order, @Headers MessageHeaders headers, Message message, Session session) {
        log.info("---> Consumer1 - rde_receiver_queue - " + order.getContent());

        throw new ValidationException("Voluntary exception", "entity", List.of(), List.of());
    }
```

Is it normal that the redelivery policy and the DLQ mechanismd do only apply for a queue (anycat queue)? 
Is it possible to also apply it for topic (multicast queue) and shared durable subscriptions? 
If not, how can I have a topic behaviour but with redelivery and DLQ mechanisms? Should I use the divert solution of ActiveMQ?

Thank a lot for your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. It comes from Atomikos that does not support the JMS v2.0 but only JMS 1.1.
So, it's not possible to get a shared durable subscription on a topic that support at the same time the 2-PC and the redelivery policy.

Comment: Why does the transaction manager need to support JMS 2?

Comment: Because it wraps the JMS objects to manage the transaction.

Comment: If this is the correct answer please mark it as such to help others who have this same problem in the future. Thanks!